# How to stop my cat peeing in the hallway

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, urination

My cat (7 year old female) has started peeing in the hallway, we have had to take up the floor because of a leak, and now there is exposed concrete, and a small dug out channel where the pipes run (this was 8 months ago, still not fixed by the landlord). This is mostly covered by wooden boards, but there is a small gap where you can see into the channel. The channel is about 2 inches deep and 3 inches wide.

Within the last 2 weeks the cat has decided to pee there, in three different spots (within 1m of each other).

Her sister, with whom she has lived for her entire life, uses the litter tray as normal. There have been no changes to the household, me and the cats live alone. There have been no diet changes, she eats and drinks as normal, there is no blood in the pee.

I took the offending cat to the vet, who checked for infections and he said there was nothing wrong with her. He suggested to put the litter tray over the area she was peeing, so I did. The cat still decided to pee on the wooden board/the channel.

I have used enzymatic cleaner on the area she has peed too, I was hoping this would have removed the smell, to discourage her from going there, but it seems to have made no difference.

Can anyone give me any hints as to what might be causing this, and how to get her back to using the litter tray? By the way, she still poops in the litter tray.

Comment: You already did everything I would have suggested in an answer. The best idea is to completely cover the area with a plastic or rubber mat so her urine cannot soak into the wood or concrete.

Comment: I am sorry but closed because duplicate, if you think we did a mistake closing your question then please explain in comments why and click "reopen" to get people to vote whether to reopen it.